# PHP equation to calculate stores profits by rank

Tags: php, math, rank

Based on the information from this [referralcandy](https://www.referralcandy.com/blog/how-many-online-stores-are-there-in-the-us-2013-edition/) article, I conclude that I need to calculate the store's profit by rank using the following power equation:

```
revenue = (1.25 * 10 ^ 13) / (x ^ 1.54);
```

i plug the Alexa rank of the site I'm are looking into X and the equation will give you an estimate of revenue.

so the question is how could I do this using PHP, what I tried so far is:

```
function getStoreRevenueByRank(int $rank)
    {
        return (1.25 * 10 ^ 13) / ($rank ^ 1.54); // 0.0034982508745627 (incorrect)
    }
```

While you can see the correct [google calculator result](https://www.google.com/search?q=%281.25%20*%2010%20%5E%2013%29%20%2F%20%28140000%20%5E%201.54%29&sxsrf=ALeKk02VbAX5qN48u_4_Hay8m73nFPKl8A%3A1618091087471&ei=TxxyYMGsHIi4a6SNkbAD&oq=%281.25%20*%2010%20%5E%2013%29%20%2F%20%28140000%20%5E%201.54%29&gs_lcp=Cgdnd3Mtd2l6EAM6BwgjELADECc6BwgAEEcQsANQmNIDWKquBGCcsQRoAnACeACAAa0DiAGmD5IBCTAuNy4yLjAuMZgBAKABAqABAaoBB2d3cy13aXrIAQrAAQE&sclient=gws-wiz&ved=0ahUKEwiBkO6D0_TvAhUI3BoKHaRGBDYQ4dUDCA0&uact=5).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In PHP `^` translates to the `XOR` operator.

Your function should use the `**` operator:

```
function getStoreRevenueByRank(int $rank):float
{
    return (1.25 * 10 ** 13) / ($rank ** 1.54);
}
```